# Usage of "sitting still", "standing still" etc

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm occasionaly came across the phrases:

- "sitting still";
- "standing still";
- "lying still";
- etc.

For most cases the usage is clear (humans for example). But sometimes it is not clear what verb to use with "still":

- for an spherical objects - I have no idea;
- birds - I think they are "standing";
- fish - again, no idea;
- and so on.

Is there any advice on how to choose an appropriate answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Sit, stand,* and *lie* are verbs that all refer to the prototypic human body.
They represent three basic body orientations: respectively, vertical, folded, and horizontal.

These verbs have a number of common peculiarities:

- they are all very, very common
- they are all intransitive
- they all describe a state, but allow the progressive - *He's just standing/sitting/lying there.*
- they are all irregular - *sit, sat, sat; stand, stood, stood; lie, lay, lain*
- they all have irregular inchoative/causative related verbs: *set; stand; lay*
  (parenthetically, this is where the *sit/set* and *lie/lay* problems come from)

Combined with an attributive predicate `A` that can describe the human body, any of these verbs can mean 'sit/stand/lie in a(n) `A` manner'. So *sit still, stand rigid, lie limp*, etc.

As far as other animals are concerned, if you can metaphorize a **human** body on them, they can sit, stand, or lie. But not necessarily with the same body parts -- when a dog or cat is *standing still*, it's likely using four legs, not two; but when it's *standing up* it may well be using only two.

It depends, in other words, on your metaphorical image. And [metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) are **always** literally incorrect, since they violate the Law of Contradiction.

Comment: To specifically address the "fish" question, the most idiomatic English expression is that they are *standing still*, despite the fact that they have no legs at all. The same applies to most inanimate objects.

Comment: _Standing still_ is in opposition to any movement verb, since _to be still_ means not to move. So fish and worms and even amoeba can stand still. Indeed, the [phonosemantics of ST-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf) reinforces this.

Answer (score 0):

Inanimate objects can be said to *lie still* (not *lay*, at least in British English): "Dear God! the very houses seem asleep;/
And all that mighty heart is lying still!" Wordsworth, *Upon Westminster Bridge* , among many other examples.

Birds, as I understand it, have insufficient joints to do anything but *stand* (unless they are stationary while flying, which is *hovering*).

What fish do is a good question. *Lying still*, like inanimate objects, is probably what I would use, but I don't know any canonical answer.

Comment: As noted in a finstofeet.com article under heading [What about the bird foot?](http://finstofeet.com/2010/07/04/taking-wing-huxley-history-and-hind-feet/#5), it is true that  “the various bones of the lower tarsus and the metatarsus are fused into a single skeletal unit called the “Tarsometatarsus” [and] The tibia and the upper tarsal bones are fused to form the “Tibiotarsus””, but nevertheless, birds can crouch and they can sit (as on a nest) as well as stand