# 'To lie' and 'to lay' / 'to rise' and 'to raise' / 'to fall' and 'to fell' <-- Did English used to have more pairs like this?

Tags: grammar, history, historical-change, transitivity

My understanding is that there aren't many pairs of intransitive and transitive verbs in modern English. Off-hand, I know of three (though I think there are more):

- lie vs lay
- rise vs raise
- fall vs fell

There are of course verbs which can be both on their own without a sound change, but I'm not interested in those.

The question then is, did we ever have more of these pairs such that they simply fell out of use over time? Or did we only ever have a small amount?

If we did lose them, about which generation of English did we lose them in?

Comment: Those are actually causatives signalled by vowel mutation: *lay* means to cause to lie, *raise* means to cause to lie, *fell*  means to cause to fall. [See here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/95218) for causatives with other kinds of mutations, both vocalic and affricate, and some of the history behind this phenomenon.

Comment: I [answered this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/153332/15299) a while back.  There's also [_sit/set_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/169730/15299).

Comment: @JohnLawler thanks for this, though I think the question still stands while the terminology can just be made more specific. You say "As usual, however, when there is an intransitive inchoative verb for a particular state, there is also a transitive causative verb" - but how do those pairs look and how frequent are those words to begin with? Did we perhaps used to have more connected by a simple sound change as these are?

Comment: They're not pairs, they're triples - a stative predicate, an inchoative  predicate, and a causative predicate. Logically, STATE (x), CHANGE (STATE (x)), and CAUSE (y, CHANGE (STATE (x))). _Bill is alive/dead, Bill died, Frank killed Bill_. CHANGE usually defaults to START or STOP, but it can get complicated. As to what they look like, there is no rule, or rather the rules have varied over the centuries. Look for the meanings and uses. Also, when there is a special inchoative verb, it can often be used as a causative, too.

Comment: It should be noted that the claim that "lay" is only transitive [is not supported by the evidence.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20would%20lay%20down%20on%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2018,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en)

Comment: It is statistically more likely that the number of such verbs has fallen over the years as old verbs are lost and new verbs, on the whole, tend to be weak and regular.

Comment: I frankly don't see what can be substituted for this usage: He lay the dress shirts on the bed.